# What is the recommended way to avoid repeated code in ManagedBeans?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

As for good user feedback, I am using messages on multiple sites in my webapplication.

To add a message, I simple use:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(type, "", message));
```

I added variables for `type` and `message`, because it depends on different validation.

Well, I am using different `ManagedBeans` for different sites, this is just normal.

It came to my mind, what is the best practice for adding those messages in different `ManagedBeans`.

Currently, I am always using the above code snippet like over 30 times (and it will become more and more for sure).

Should I create a Bean with `SessionScoped`annotated or `@ApplicationScoped`? Do you have any other hints, that should I know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just hide away repeated static code into a reusable `static` method to make it more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ("Don't Repeat Yourself").

Design the static method in such way that you can ultimately refactor from this,

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(type, "", message));
```

to something like this,

```
Messages.addGlobalInfo(message);
```

or even with an `import static com.example.Messages.*;` (Eclipse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> the line):

```
addGlobalInfo(message);
```

It doesn't need to be a managed bean as it doesn't hold any state. Moreover, you should make the default constructor of such an utility class `private`, so Java/JSF can in first place already not construct it via `new` operator or `Class#newInstance()` in reflection. If you're using CDI, annotate it if necessary with [`@Typed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Typed.html) with an empty value to prevent it from being registered as managed bean candidate via [`Bean<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/Bean.html).

```
@Typed
public final class Messages {

    private Messages() {}

    // ...
}
```

JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has exactly this utility class: [`org.omnifaces.util.Messages`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Messages).

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing to this class (wirtten by yourself). I used `Messages#addGlobal(Severity,String)`. I guess, if you already use OmniFaces, it is much cleaner than the other way.

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed, almost all repeated JSF code eventually end up in OmniFaces.

Answer (score 2):

May be just move this code to some utility class:

```
public void static addMessage(FacesMessage.Severity type, String message){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(type, "", message));
}
```

Also you can create several methods with one argument: addInfoMessage, addErrorMessage, ...

Comment: And how should I annotate this utility class?